# get href value from a website to chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making an extension and i want to do the following-

suppose i want my extension to work only on say, xyz.com, which contains the following line-

```
<a href="xyz.com/abcd" class="abcd">abcd</a>
```

How do I retrieve href value from xyz.com's code into my extension using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing: if you are trying to have your extension loaded whenever a page in the domain xyz.com is opened then you can just [set your permissions appropriately](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions) and it should work.

Comment: Actually xyz.com has a search box, so i want to get the value of href of a certain class from the page- "hxxp://www.xyz.com/query="+searchterm
Is it possible to do it by just setting the permissions to the domain xyz.com ?